# Memory management in Tensorflow's Dataset API

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a training dataset that is too big to fit into memory, so my code reads only 1,000 records from disk at a time. Now I would like to use Tensorflow's new [Dataset API](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/docs_src/programmers_guide/datasets.md). Does the Dataset API allow me to specify the number of records to keep in memory or does Tensorflow automatically manage memory so that I don't have to?

Comment: I revisited your question. Batch_size in a combination with shuffle works for sure.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. An example from official guide (Using the Dataset API for TensorFlow Input Pipelines, https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets)

```
filenames = ["/var/data/file1.tfrecord", "/var/data/file2.tfrecord"]
dataset = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
dataset = dataset.map(...) ## Parsing data with a user specified function
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000) ## 10000: size of sample/record pool for random selection
dataset = dataset.repeat() ## None: keep repeating
dataset = dataset.batch(32) ## 32: number of samples/records per batch (to be read into memory)
```

Comment: the order should be shuffle, repeat, batch, then prefetch

Comment: @ArtificiallyIntelligence Thanks, updated the order as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If you will specify the number of records via [batch_size](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/Dataset). In this case TF will grab only batch_size elements from the file. You can also specify [shuffle](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/Dataset#shuffle) and this will guarantee that all the time in the memory will be at maximum `buffer_size` elements.

I verified it on my tfrecords files. I have 100 tfrecords files, each of them is ~10Gb (which is more than the memory on my laptop). And everything works fine.

Comment: Unless I've overlooked something, the docs simply say that a batch: "combines consecutive elements of this dataset into batches." I didn't see anything about memory management or how the data is read from disk. Also, what I've seen so far suggests that Datasets is replacing queues, for example see this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7951#issuecomment-303744600

Comment: @user554481 wow, didn't know that. This is the first time I saw dataset and thought that this is just a helper. Thank you

Comment: interesting.. it is usually suggested that one should only use O(100MB) for his tfrecord files...